# Getting Incorrect padding error while decoding a message in pyhon when the encoding is from base64 in java

Tags: python, java, encoding, base64, decoding

I have a service in python which will decode the messages like below:

```
json.loads(base64.b64decode(myMessage['data']))
```

This is what I am trying to do in Java to encode

```
JSONObject msg=new JSONObject();
msg.put("name", "myName");
msg.put("class", "myClass");
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        obj.put("data",Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(msg.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

When I am encoding in the above way getting `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding` error in python. Is there anyway I can send encoded base64 message from Java which will be accepted by my python code.

When I try to encode in python

```
msg = {}
msg["name"] = "myName"
msg["class"] = "myClass"
res = {}
res["data"] =  base64.b64encode(json.dumps(msg).encode("utf-8"))
```

It is working fine. I am not sure what I am missing in java.

Note: I can't make changes in the decoder which is in python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you can't change the python code it would still be helpful if you could show how your python code decodes the message so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ThomasKläger This is how decoding is happening in python json.loads(base64.b64decode(myMessage['data']))

Comment: Could you add `System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(msg.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));` to your Java code and `print(myMessage['data'])` to your python code and include the results in your question (assuming that you can do so without including confidential data)?